# How do I access my images in my drawable folder using the name of file?

Tags: android, image, android-studio

Good evening the fact is that I can not access my images by the names of the files, if not by a random number (?) Assigned in android, I realized this when by means of a toast I saw that the method:

```
Uri .parse ("android.resource: //" + R.class.getPackage (). getName () + "/" + portrait_artist) .toString ();
```

returned the string: `"android.resource: //test.com.myapplication/2131165274"`
 instead of the String `android.resource://test.com.myapplication/nameofmyfile.png`

and then I do not know how to access my file by name original, I am currently accessing the number that returns, but I need to add other images to the project and I would like to add them by the file name, sorry if my question is ridiculous I am new in this android, I add, I'm using Piccaso visualize the image , Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you have the **image name** and you can use this method to access the image from `drawable` directory.

```
public Drawable getImage(String imageName) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable",
            context.getPackageName());
    return resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`int imageRes[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,...};`

then

```
for(int i =0; i<3;i++){

  //your toast or content here

  imageArray[i] = imageRes[indices[i]];

  //use images where ever you want
}
```

That may help you... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "getResources().getIdentifier(...)": 
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)